# How do I append a range of JSON data to my HTML using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What I am trying to do is to break-up what I grab from my JSON file. For example say my JSON data looks like this:

```
{
"paintings": {
  "painting": [
    {
    "title": "Boardwalk 5",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap1.jpg",
    "price": 850
    },
    {
    "title": "A Lasting Piece",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap2.jpg",
    "price": 450
    },
    {
    "title": "Surf at High Tide",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap3.jpg",
    "price": 950
    },
    {
    "title": "The Games We Play",
    "artist": "Arnie Palmer",
    "image": "ap4.jpg",
    "price": 850
    }
  ]
} 
}
```

I want append to `<div class="area1">` the first 2 items in my JSON array then append items 3 and 4  to `<div class="area2">`. Here is how I am pulling all my data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: jsonParser
});
});

function jsonParser(json) {
$('#load').fadeOut();

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
    $.each(data.paintings.painting, function(k,v){
        var title = v.title;
        var img = v.image;
        var price = v.price;
///here is where I need help
        $('.area1').append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
    });
});
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="area1">...first half of JSON data here... </div>
<div class="area2">... second half of JSON data here </div>
</body>
```

So one JSON file with the data broken up then appended to two areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more verbose than @Rhumborls solution.

```js
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.paintings.painting, function(k, v) {
    var title = v.title;
    var img = v.image;
    var price = v.price;
    var areaid;

    switch (k) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
        areaid = '.area1';
        break;

      case 2:
      case 3:
        areaid = '.area2';
        break;
    }

    $(areaid).append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
  });
});
```

Or even more scalable

```js
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.paintings.painting, function(k, v) {
    var title = v.title;
    var img = v.image;
    var price = v.price;

    // We figure out the area to append to by rounding down to nearest 10 and plus by 1
    // key of 0-9 becomes 1, key of 10-19 becomes 2 i.e.
    var areaid = '.area' + (Math.round(k / 10) + 1);

    $(areaid).append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
  });
});
```

Comment: That really depends on if he has to expand. This is more scalable.

Comment: You so be so kind to provide a scaled example? I can easily see the JSON file populating to well over 30 objects.  Perhaps stream 10 objects to a div? Perhaps create a new div area for every 10 items as they get added?

Comment: Im not sure I understand. You want the function to loop through the paintings (in theory an infinite number), and for every 10 paintings append to a new div?

Comment: Yes for every 10 paintings, append to a new div.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the index (`k`) in your `each()` function to decide which area to add to:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
    $.each(data.paintings.painting, function(k,v){
        var title = v.title;
        var img = v.image;
        var price = v.price;

        // k is the index in the array. indexes 0 and 1 go to area1. 2 and 3 go to area2
        var areaid = k < 2 ? '.area1' : '.area2';
        $(areaid).append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var url = "json.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data.paintings.painting, function(k, v) {
            var title = v.title;
            var img = v.image;
            var price = v.price;
            if (k < 2) {
                $('.area1').append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>');
            } else {
                $('.area2').append('<div class="painting"><img src="images/' + img + '" width="200" height="225" alt="' + title + '" /><br/><div class="title">' + title + '<br/>$' + price + '</div></div>')
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I like the way this reads. What if I get 30 items populated in my JSON file (instead of the four) and what to append that up into three div areas? Perhaps create a new div area for every 10 items as they get added.

Comment: Well if you have 30 items, it wouldnt matter. This will iterate through them all already. If you have any other conditions just add more if and else statements. For example, you may say if().. else if().. else if()... else()